# Is there a way for `npm pack` to include all dependency packages recursively instead of just the base package? Why does it do that?

Tags: npm

For example in this picture:

[image]

`npm pack` only packages the contents of `electron-builder@22.8.1`, but I'd like it to package all of the required 14 dependencies and then its children dependencies recursively until I know I could use `electron-builder@22.8.1` correctly with a `npm install` with no troubles.

Is there a way to do this?

Why does `npm pack` only do the top level instead of all the packages associated with it?

For context, I'm going this way instead of simply `npm install electron-builder` because I'm packaging these items to be installed in an offline computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a CLI tool ([GitHub](https://github.com/tar-erpedia/deep-pack), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tar-erpedia/deep-pack)) to recursively pack dependencies for offline networks.

basic usage: `npm-deep-pack <package_name>`

There was already a cool tool named package-bundle ([GitHub](https://github.com/alexbrazier/package-bundle),[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-bundle)) but i had some troubles with it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [npm-offline-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-offline-packager) for this all the time.

Once you've installed it by running `npm i -g npm-offline-packager`, just run `npo fetch --no-cache --peer <package name>`.